# Populate combobox access 2007 using vba with postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, vba, odbc

I'm trying to populate a combobox with records from a table filtered by a parent combobox.
The table I want to filter is called muni and parent table is called prov. They are related by a common field (muni has a field called gid_prov that contains prov gid for each record)
First combobox stores the prov gid and shows the prov name.
Both tables are in a database from postgresql connected to access by an DSN file using ODBC.
I have tried many options, and none is correct.
First I tried a simple option. This code is useless now

```
Private Sub PROV_Change()
   MUNI.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
   MUNI.RowSource = "select *  from memoria.muni  where gid_provs =" & PROV
   MUNI.Requery
   MUNI.SetFocus
   MUNI.Text = ""

   End Sub
```

PROV is the name of the parent combobox that stores the prov gid. And MUNI the combobox I want to populate.
Other option I tried was creating a query with an sql statement, this is the code right now, i tried with the OpenRecordsetOutput, but is not working. I can access the database and get the fields, but I can't populate the combobox MUNI

```
     Private Sub PROV_Change()
    Dim oDb As DAO.Database
    Dim oRs As DAO.Recordset
    dbconnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI;UID=***;PWD=***;PORT=5432;SERVER=127...;DATABASE=memoria_historica;DSN=C:\Users\***"
    Set oDb = OpenDatabase("", False, False, dbconnect)
Dim sql As String
sql = "select gid,nombre  from memoria.municipios m where m.gid_provs =" & PROV & "order by m.nombre;"
Set oRs = oDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSQLPassThrough)
Me.muni2.RowSource = ""
If oRs.RecordCount > 0 Then
With oRs
.MoveFirst
.MoveNext

Do While Not .EOF
                    muni2.AddItem .Fields("nombre").Value

                    .MoveNext
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Worked fine tih the support of @Thaippo. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and update your code to what it is now? I imagine it's nothing like what you'r showing above

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working fine. Finally to populate the id_muni field I made another query on change like this

Comment: `If oRs.recordCount>0 Then
   Me.txtTextbox=oRs!gid
Else
   Me.txtTextbox="N/A"
End If

Set oRs=Nothing
Set oDb=Nothing    
End Sub` from @Fiounnala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you DAO library.

You could you DAO. Database and DAO. Recordset like:

```
Dim oDb as DAO.Database
Dim oRs as DAO.Recordset
```

Your second block of codes could do the work.

```
Set oDb = OpenDatabase("", False, False, dbconnect)
Dim sql As String
sql = "select m.nombre  from memoria.muni 
m,memoria.prov p where st_within(m.the_geom,p.the_geom) and p.gid =" & PROV ";"

Set oRs = oDb.Openrecordset(sql) 

If oRs.Recordcount > 1 Theb
With oRs
.Movelast
.Movefirst

Do while not.EOF
                    PROV.Additem . Fields("nameOfFieldsYouNeed"). Value
                    .Movenext
Loop
End With

End if
```

And it's would be a good idea to clear the combox box before adding new items in it.

Comment: And sorry for not formatting blocks of codes,  I'm on my cellphone! I'll edit later when ill be home

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not working. The oDb.Openrecordset(sql) tries to open a Database in my local machine, it says "Error, cannot find database C:\Users\Documents\memoria.mdb". I don't understand why, because dbconnect is calling the ODBC driver DSN. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried using the dbSnapshot in recordset Type and dbSQLPassThrough in the Options, and now I don't have this error now, but the filter is not working. I'm completely lost :-(

Comment: Hi @Thapipo I have achieved a solution thanks to your code. I need now to clear the combobox, do you have any hint? I tried combobox.Clear(); combobox.SelectedIndex = -1, and other, but it's not working. Thanks!